# Use fixedDelay with @Scheduled parallelStream and ForkJoinPool

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

I am trying to run a scheduler & process 2 records in parallel at a time.

**Code:**

```
@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3000)
public void run() {
  System.out.println("Run");
  runJob();
}
```

```
public void runJob() {
 ForkJoinPool pool = new ForkJoinPool(2);
 List<String> list = Arrays.asList("1","2","3");
 pool.submit(() -> list.parallelStream().forEach(this::execute));

 pool.shutdown();
}
```

**Issue:**

This issue is `fixedDelay` parameter is supposed to wait for the entire processing to be completed before scheduling next task, but in my case it's not waiting and keep on scheduling new tasks after every 3 seconds.

My requirement is to wait for the processing to complete before scheduling a new task.
Could you please help?

Comment: There is nothing to wait in your `run` method because you execute your tasks in another threads, so `runJob` finishes immediately

Comment: perhaps you wanted to wait for completion instead of just calling [`shutdown`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#shutdown()) in `runJob()`? "This method does not wait for previously submitted tasks to complete execution. Use [`awaitTermination`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html#awaitTermination(long,java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)) to do that."